# Music file plays for 45 seconds and then stops in android app

Tags: java, android, mp3

I am trying to make a game by using android studio and Java for my android phone. When I put a music file into the app it plays but it only plays for 45 seconds and stops. I have tested it on several other music files to see if it is somehow the music file and I still get the same error. My goal is to have the music play on a loop like in a game. I have tried various youtube videos and looked at other websites but I would still get the either the same problem or can't compile code.

```
package com.example.androidstudio2dgamedevelopment;


import static android.media.MediaPlayer.*;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Main Activity is the entry point to our application
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    MediaPlayer bkgrdmsc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = create(this, R.raw.fg);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        //Set Window to fullscreen (will hide status bar)
        Window window = getWindow();
                this.width = (240);
                this.height = (240);

        //Set Content view to game, so that objects in the Game Class can be rendered to the screen
        setContentView(new Game(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what it was. Here is the code that I used and it worked for me. I tend to no being able to finding out the answers to my questions until I ask them.

```
package com.example.androidstudio2dgamedevelopment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Main Activity is the entry point to our application
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    MediaPlayer mysong;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mysong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bc);
        mysong.start();
        mysong.setLooping(true);

        //Set Window to fullscreen (will hide status bar)
        Window window = getWindow();
                this.width = (240);
                this.height = (240);

        //Set Content view to game, so that objects in the Game Class can be rendered to the screen
        setContentView(new Game(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mysong.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is what I think I did wrong.

I used `MediaPlayer` as a variable instead of `mysong` which seemed to work for me. I also forgot to add `MainActivity` before the `this` in the code that I posted.

```
        mysong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bc);
        mysong.start();
        mysong.setLooping(true);
```

I also added this at the end.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mysong.release();
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add setLooping(true) for Media Player.

```
Uri uri = createUri(context, R.raw.fg);
Mediaplayer mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.start();
```